# python print a string in array format

Tags: python, arrays, string, printing

I passed an argument to a python script like `-b bench`. The `bench` is created like this:

```
bench_dir = '~/myFD/'
bench_bin = bench_dir + 'src/bin/Assembler'
bench_inp1 = bench_dir + 'input/in.fa'
bench_out1 = bench_dir + 'output/data.scratch'

bench= LiveProcess()
bench.executable = bench_bin
bench.cwd = bench_dir
bench.cmd = [bench.executable] + ['-s', bench_out1, '<', bench_inp1]
```

The `bench.cmd` should looks like:

```
~/myFD/src/bin/Assembler -s ~/myFD/output/data.scratch < ~/myFD/input/in.fa
```

to do that, I use `print bench.cmd` but it doesn't show the above statment correctly. Instead it shows:

```
['~/myFD/src/bin/Assembler', '-s', '~/myFD/output/data.scratch', ' < ', '~/myFD/input/in.fa']
```

how can I fix that?

Comment: Don't have it be a list. That's it.

Comment: did you want `print ' '.join(bench.cmd)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `print ' '.join(bench.cmd)`. This joins the list and uses a space as delimiter

Answer (score 2):

You could do `' '.join(bench.cmd)`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this,

```
>>> mylist = ['~/myFD/src/bin/Assembler', '-s', '~/myFD/output/data.scratch', ' < ', '~/myFD/input/in.fa']
>>> " ".join(mylist)
'~/myFD/src/bin/Assembler -s ~/myFD/output/data.scratch  <  ~/myFD/input/in.fa'
```

or just concatenate your strings

```
bench.cmd = bench.executable + ' -s ' + bench_out1 + ' < ' + bench_inp1
```

Answer (score 0):

case for join: `' '.join(bench.cmd)`

Comment: @user1180720 for some reason that caused me to choke on my drink. Thanks.